# I've assigned another class that draws images to a JPanel in the main JFrame, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I tried to create a JPanel and apply graphics to it, but only a blank screen appears.

I created a new class that extends JPanel and assigned it to an arbitrary panel in the main JFrame.
(inGamePanel is JPanel in main JFrame)

Below is the code in main JFrame

```java
inGamePanel = new GameStart(songList.get(currentSong), inGamePanel.getGraphics());
inGamePanel.setVisible(true);
```

Below is the another class that extends JPanel

```java
package RhythmGame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameStart extends JPanel {
    
    private Song currentSong;
    private Graphics gameGraphics;
    private ImageIcon inGameImage;
    
    public GameStart(Song currentSong, Graphics gameGraphics) {
        this.currentSong = currentSong;
        this.gameGraphics = gameGraphics;
        paintComponent(gameGraphics);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        inGameImage = currentSong.getSongBackgroundImage();
        
        g.drawImage(inGameImage.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The main Jframe has a CardLayout applied to it. What's the matter?

I want to display a JPanel with an image normally applied to the screen.

Comment: Not enough code. You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you will need to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) - the short answer is, you should never call any `paint` method directly